# PHP Insert data into mysql on duplicate key update - add suffix

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

want insert a duplicate entry into mysql with a suffix. here is an example:

```
+-------+--------------+-------+
| ID    | Title        | url   |
+-------+--------------+-------+

+-------+--------------+-------+
| 1     | test         | test1 |
+-------+--------------+-------+
| 2     | test         | test2 |
+-------+--------------+-------+
| 3     | test         | test3 |
+-------+--------------+-------+
```

means, i want to add auto number as suffix to end of each url that have duplicate title. titles are duplicated but url are kinda unique.

**Here is query:**

```
 $i = 0;
    $i++;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `content` (title, text, cat, url, tag)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["title"]."', '".$_POST["text"]."', '".$_POST["category"]."', '".$_POST["url"]."', '".$_POST["tag"]."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=".$_POST["url"]."+". $i ."";
```

note: url made dynamically based on title entry.
this query not working, what is wrong with my code?

**UPDATE:** here is error after run query:

> error: INSERT INTO `content` (title, text, cat, url, tag) VALUES
>   ('test', '', '16', 'test', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=test+1
>   Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @davidvelilla it's not clear? please read 1st line in my question: want insert a duplicate entry into mysql with a suffix. my query not working.

Comment: Ah. Okay. We are getting there. You didn't mention that your query wasn't working. So what exactly are you getting when you run the query and it does not work?

Comment: @davidvelilla sorry for that. actually nothing,it just leave empty, URL field. i pretty sure query is wrong but don't know what is correct. error updated in question

Comment: @davidvelilla question updated.

Comment: Much better. Checkout my answer, it explains the process rather than giving you code right away, but it's better to understand what's going on rather than copying-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some strange things. $i = 0; followed by $i++; is just equivalent than doing $i = 1; But then again, what's the purpose on setting a variable that you only use once?

What you really need to do is:

1. INSERT query forgetting about the "url" field and removing the ON DUPLICATE...
2. Get the ID of the last insert. Have a look at the following link to see how to get that value: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp
3. UPDATE query to set the value of "url"

   ```
   $_POST["url"].$id_of_last_query
   ```